# Are dpi and pixel in Photoshop are just the same?

Tags: pixel, dpi

This one bothers me, I'm still new on Android UI designing. Are dpi and pixel in Photoshop are just the same?

Like if I will create a xhdpi with 320dpi, the 320dpi is just the same settings on 320 pixels/inch resolution?

Because when I designed for example an icons like launcher icon 96x96 xhdpi, my settings on resolution is 320 pixels/inch resolution on Photoshop. Then I will just resize the image thru image resizing on resolution. (example: The 320 resolution for xhdpi will be change to 240 for hdpi) Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, for Photoshop, they are different. If you wanna design for Android, you have to provide 4 different files of the same asset: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xdpi. They differ at dimension. You can take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.

In my opinion, a vector program like Illu or Inkscape will do the job better: dpi in Android and export dpi are the same. Create your UI at 72 screen dpi, export with different dpi after that.